# Some issues with standardized variable in a regression analysis

Tags: normalization, standardization

I'm solving this multiple choice question on the properties of a standardized variable. Two of the possible options (which are wrong but look right to me) are 1. It is always normally distributed and 2. it has a bell shaped distribution.

I've been googling and apparently, standardizing a variable does not change the shape of the curve. So if we have a non normal distribution- standardizing it wont change its shape. However, I thought one of the defining characteristic of a Z distribution was that it was symmetric.

If a normal distribution is always symmetric, and a Z distribution is always symmetric, how can we have a non normal standard distribution? Can we have a distribution that is not bell shaped and still standardized? I'm trying to think of examples but can't.

Comment: Is the variable normally distributed before the standardization?

Comment: Its a general multiple choice question. Is it possible to standardize a non normally distributed variable? Because our teacher told us that we convert a variable to Z value only if its normally distributed.

Comment: Standardization is a general term. But as analog to normal distribution, any distribution in the class of distributions called location-scale distributions can be location centered and set to unit scale. Therefore if the variable is not normal before standardization both #1 and #2 are false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standardizing a set of scores—that is, converting them to *z*-scores—that is, subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation—indeed will not make a distribution any more or less normal. It won't make an asymmetric distribution symmetric, either. A set of *z*-scores is not necessarily a "*z*-distribution", whether the term "*z*-distribution" means a normal distribution or something more exotic like [Fisher's *z*-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_z-distribution).

An easy example of a standardized set of scores that is obviously neither normal nor otherwise bell-shaped is (-1.46, -0.88, -0.29, 0.29, 0.88, 1.46). This dataset has mean 0 and standard deviation 1 but is uniformly distributed. I produced it by standardizing (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).